# Functions in different contexts in HTML-embedded javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Not sure if the title of the question is right, but anyway here's my problem. I have an php/html document with embedded javascript. I have two functions, `showSys` and `showPies`. Both functions are inside the same `<script>` tag at the beginning of the document, so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showSys(){...}

    function showPies(){...}
</script>
```

Further below in the document, I have a table. `showSys` is called in an `onClick()` context for the contents of some of the `<td>` elements in the table. `showPies` is called inside some of the other `<td>` elements of the table. So

```
<table>
  <tr>
  ...
    <td><a onClick="showSys()">blah</a></td>
  ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
  ...
    <td><script type='text/javascript'>showPies()</script></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that with the above code, `showSys()` is not called. Only `showPies()` is called. I'm sure it is something to do with the execution context, but I can't figure it out -- I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to JavaScript. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2):

`showSys()` is only going to be called when that table cell (td) is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Your script works for me. Are you actually clicking "blah"?

```html
<script>
  function showSys() {
    alert('showSys');
    }
  function showPies() {
    alert('showPies');
    }
  </script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onClick="showSys();return false;">blah</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><script type='text/javascript'>showPies()</script></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So on mouseover, I can't click blah. The mouse doesn't change to a "finger" and I can't click it with the pointer either.

Comment: I have to add that I'm using php echo statements to generate the table, because it's created inside a php script.

Comment: Just because it doesn't change to a pointer, doesn't mean it's not clickable. You have to add the `href` attribute to the `<a>` tag to make it turn into a pointer (or you can do it w/ CSS but its less compatible). I'll update my answer....